# How to calculate minimum distance between point and line in 3D space

Tags: geolocation, geospatial

I need to calculate the minimum distance between a 3D point (latitude, longitude, elevation) and a line (defined as two points).
The elevation is not necessary on the ground, I need to consider flying objects.
I only found an article that explains how to do that on a generic space but my points are defined with lat/lon/altitude(meters).

Thank you for pointing in the right direction, in my case I need to do that in Javascript but couldn't find any library that takes into consideration the altitude.

[Point-Line Distance--3-Dimensional](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance3-Dimensional.html)

Comment: Do you want the exact mathematical formulas and implement it yourself, or do you have something like PostGIS that you can use?

Comment: Thanks, I can use any library that can do that. Also interested in the maths behind but not a priority.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare a 3d point to a 2d line, I suppose you mean a "line" on our earth, at elevation 0. Take a look at `st_distance` in postgis.

If I understand you correctly, that'll give you what you want.

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html

Comment: The "line" is an airplane trajectory so not on earth.